# On using MongoDb Client v3.0, it shows the error “db.collection” not a function

Tags: mongodb

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient; 
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb"; 
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err)
 throw err; 
db.collection("OTPs").findOne({}, function(err, result) { 
if (err)
throw err;
 console.log(OTPs.name);
 db.close();
 }); 
});
```

Error Message:
TypeError: db.collection is not a function

Comment: Kindly read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and modify your question.

Answer (score 0):

From version 3 the syntax have changed to get a `db` object as the function only provides a `client` object  , then try the following

```
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb"; 
MongoClient.connect(url, (err, client) => {
  // Client returned
  var db = client.db('mytestingdb');
if (err)
 throw err; 
db.collection("OTPs").findOne({}, function(err, result) { 
if (err)
throw err;
 console.log(OTPs.name);
 db.close();
 }); 
});
```